# Present Perfect in reviews

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, tenses, present-perfect, simple-past

When explaining an experiment from a paper which one of the following seems more suitable and natural.

> In this paper they study the genetic structure of human body. They *have* examined over 100 patients...

Or should it be simple past:

> In this paper they study the genetic structure of human body. They examined over 100 patients...

Answer (score 2):

Neither. All four sentences have article mistakes. They should be

- *In this paper they study the genetic structure of **the** human body.* (***the*** required here)
- *They (have) examined over 100 patients...*

As for the perfect construction with *have*, probably that's not necessary.

Scientific reports generally use specific tenses and constructions for different parts of an experimental paper. For instance, if the experimenters built a piece of equipment that is still available, they might use a perfect construction, but, if the piece of equipment is **not** still available, they'd use simple past instead.

Your best course of action is therefore to use whatever tenses and constructions the paper uses in your own report. If they wrote *"We examined"*, you write "*They examined"*; if they wrote *"We have examined"*, you write "*They have examined"*.

Don't try to second-guess the author, or the author's grammar, unless you're the editor of the journal it's being published in.

Comment: Thanks. What if it's a survey that they have taken?

Comment: I don't think you can put a survey into a "taken" state, so _*I will have the survey taken by next week_ sounds very bad to me. _I will have the exam taken by next week_, on the other hand, sounds fine. It's a metaphor of checking things off on a list.

Comment: Personally I think scientific papers don't usually *study* things - they tend to *examine, explore, prove*. Or maybe *undertake a study*, implying that the paper will report/analyse the *results* of the study.

Comment: Sure. Lots of choices to go around, and lots of different styles for different sciences.

Comment: @JohnLawler- No, I mean writing a review for an already completed survey paper.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular context I think *neither* form is really correct. The preceding sentence uses present tense *"they study"*, so for consistency it should be...

> They **examine** over 100 patients...

Comment: Good point, except wouldn't it be better all around to say '...they studied..'?

Comment: @Mitch: Per my comment to John's answer, I personally have misgivings about the word *study* itself here. But so far as tense is concerned, the present actually seems to be the most common option if you scan some written instances of ["in this paper we"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22in+this+paper+we%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers- Thanks. I have another related question for an activity happened in the past, while explaining the whole story in present: In this paper they examine the structure of the human body. Aside from current research, they also examine research papers that *are published* in 1997. Can this part be in simple present or should it go to simple past(were published)? Is it well written? What is the tense if we remove 'are' from 'are published'?

Comment: @Noah, I think I would phrase it: *In addition to current research, they also examine several research papers published in 1997.*" It could also be phrased, "*... that were published in 1997*" or you could drop the *papers* part altogether and say, "*In addition to current research, this paper also examines research published in 1997.*"

Comment: @Jim- Which tense does your structure use(published in 1997)? Is it simple past or present?

Comment: @Noah, simple past. The full expansion would be: "this paper also examines research [that was] published in 1997."

Comment: @Jim- Thanks. Have you had a chance to have a look at this:[If you did vs if you were](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63171/if-you-were-vs-if-you-did)

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct.

The use of the Present Perfect form denotes that the action happened in the past but the results of the action are still important in the present. The exact time of the event isn't stated because it isn't important.

The Simple Past form shows that the action happened in the past without any repercussions for the present.

I believe that the choice of the form given to the verb depends on the meaning the speaker or the writer wants to convey.